# Have Angular re-scan the DOM

Tags: angular, dom

I am inserting some new html into my Angular 2 app after a server call and I would love to have a way to "refresh" or "re-scan" so that things like (click)="myMethod()" are evaluated. All my searches for this turn up AngularJS documentation and not for the newest (version 6) of Angular.

Here is an example:

I have this tag in my html template to open a popper.

```
<li (click)="poppop();" [popper]="meetingDetails" [poppertrigger]="'click'" [popperhideonclickoutside]="true" [popperhideonscroll]="true">
    My Content
  </li>
```

Angular takes that and it ends up looking like this in the DOM:

```
<li ng-reflect-content="[object Object]" ng-reflect-show-trigger="click" ng-reflect-hide-on-click-outside="true" ng-reflect-hide-on-scroll="true">My Content</li>
```

So how I can inject the top one into the innerHTML of a tag and have it refresh into the bottom one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working like I needed using this tool:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you try to modify DOM by html, some javascript, external url, url to resource like img you need to tell angular that you actually know what you doing, therefore you need to use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusthtml).

Comment: I handled that with a custom pipe and bypassSecurityTrustHtml(). It still isn't assessing my inserted tags for angular bindings.